# Pass the selected data to another query in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a query like this in SQL Server

```
SELECT JOINT_NO_PGZ,
       MAT_0_PGZ,
       Sum(QTY_0_PGZ),
       Mat_1_PGZ,
       Sum(qty_check_1_PGZ),
       Line_Number_PGZ
FROM   [PGC].[dbo].[HISTORies]
GROUP  BY JOINT_NO_PGZ,
          Line_Number_PGZ,
          MAT_0_PGZ,
          Mat_1_PGZ
```

In the select query i have 2 columns MAT_0_PGZ and Mat_1_PGZ , i should pass these values to another table and get the result based on that table but i don't know how can i pass these values to another query i mean :

```
SELECT JOINT_NO_PGZ,
       MAT_0_PGZ,
       Sum(QTY_0_PGZ),
       Mat_1_PGZ,
       Sum(qty_check_1_PGZ),
       Line_Number_PGZ,
       ( Function(MAT_0_PGZ, Mat_1_PGZ) )
FROM   [PGC].[dbo].[HISTORies]
GROUP  BY JOINT_NO_PGZ,
          Line_Number_PGZ,
          MAT_0_PGZ,
          Mat_1_PGZ
```

I am new to SQL Server.

Best regards

Comment: Your question is too broad as we have no clue what that function call is supposed to do. You can call functions that way but I would not advise it in a GROUP BY, performance will probably be poor. Perhaps you could rethink the question and identify what it is you are actually trying to achieve rather than assuming it has to be a function call.

Comment: If you need it for just one next statement, you can wrap it in a [CTE (Common Table Expression)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - otherwise, you need to store the results into a temporary table

Answer (score 1):

You should use `insert into...`

```
insert into [your table] values (col1, col2)
```

```html
SELECT JOINT_NO_PGZ,
       MAT_0_PGZ,
       Sum(QTY_0_PGZ),
       Mat_1_PGZ,
       Sum(qty_check_1_PGZ),
       Line_Number_PGZ
FROM   [PGC].[dbo].[HISTORies]
GROUP  BY JOINT_NO_PGZ,
          Line_Number_PGZ,
          MAT_0_PGZ,
          Mat_1_PGZ
```

and than use your second query

Answer (score 0):

check this out :

```
insert into (table_name) (column_names separated by commas) (the select statement with the columns you want to transfer separated also by commas)
```

example :

```
insert into studentTable (Student_ID, Student_Class) (select Student_ID, Student_Class from StudentMarks)
```

That will work.